# pyautogui pixelMatchesColor package not existing

Tags: python, pyautogui, pixelmatch

I downloaded pyautogui and everything is up to date but I'm not able to use pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor in any way. How can I fix this?[it's not existing :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77voB.png)

I made sure everything is up to date but still , I appreciate every help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.